# Facebook Modal Popup that Prevents Scroll on Main Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

See the Facebook comment modal box in the below.  I'm trying to achieve a similar effect whereby a user clicks on a button and then it opens up a popup/modal box.  This box will allow scroll within the new box (as it could be many pages of text), but will disallow scrolling outside of the modal on the main page.  How do I achieve a similar effect where the modal allows scrolling within the modal window but not elsewhere?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Scrolling is usually prevented by adding `overflow:hidden; height:100%` to `body`. "*scrolling is not allowed anywhere. Any ideas on this?*" You want users to be able to scroll if there are no comments?

Comment: Updated to be more clear.

Comment: Would you accept jQuery solution?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  As long, as it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this works by doing the following:

- Adding `height:100%` to `body` and `html` tags.
- Adding `overflow: hidden` to `body` when the modal is showing.

---

Basic Demo: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/n4naea92/)

```js
$("body").on("click", function(){
 $("body").toggleClass("modalview");
})
```

```css
html, body {background:#666; color:#FFF; margin: 0; padding: 0; height:100%;}

#content {
  padding:1em;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#modal {
  /* hidden by default */
  display: none;
  /* box */
  width:75%;
  height:75%;
  padding:1em;
  position: fixed; z-index:1;
  overflow: auto;
  /* center modal vertically and horizontally */
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  /* style */
  text-align: center;
  background:#FFF;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 15px #000;
  color:#000;
}

/* prevent page scrollbars in modal view */
body.modalview { overflow:hidden; }

/* show #modal in modal view */
body.modalview #modal { display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal">
  <p>All UR SCROLLS ARE BELONG TO US!!!</p>
  <p>Et velit odit cumque hic, aspernatur. Perferendis assumenda est necessitatibus cupiditate cum odit deleniti doloribus earum veniam dolores, neque laudantium laboriosam optio numquam autem iure animi ipsa dolor fugit blanditiis?</p>
  <p>Unde quidem sunt quos itaque minus, quia modi nisi temporibus. Consectetur natus perferendis possimus, rem, sed tempora cumque dolorum quod provident blanditiis eum ipsam voluptate dolor, harum doloremque id amet.</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi assumenda quas, rem voluptas et, totam officia quos, quaerat doloribus eaque odio aperiam a obcaecati explicabo quod eveniet eum aliquid! Repellat.</p>
  <p>Vitae ipsum explicabo voluptatibus corrupti odio ipsa, tenetur modi veritatis excepturi architecto nam dignissimos ratione. Iusto temporibus ipsum cupiditate excepturi modi eos alias dolores eveniet possimus. Alias, esse error quam!</p>
  <p>Ea numquam quae laborum ut vitae molestias dolorum fugit, asperiores aliquid voluptates vero ab consequuntur ipsum maxime obcaecati temporibus voluptate sed quaerat, necessitatibus deleniti. Quibusdam iste saepe inventore amet eius.</p>
  <p>Aut veritatis quos quaerat, placeat nam est ad tempora delectus magnam molestiae, ipsum cupiditate debitis illum perferendis ut nisi beatae voluptas provident consectetur inventore assumenda eveniet? Molestiae architecto ullam nulla.</p>
  <p>Explicabo, debitis? Mollitia reiciendis sint minus adipisci, consectetur consequatur assumenda blanditiis pariatur ex facilis expedita et earum molestiae quos, laborum sed suscipit doloribus placeat ipsam in vero quaerat aliquid iure!</p>
  <p>Earum dolorem eveniet laboriosam vel dolor! Ullam nisi adipisci voluptatem, voluptatum tenetur, itaque ducimus laboriosam repudiandae quibusdam numquam dignissimos aperiam praesentium culpa porro sapiente ab eos magni? Maiores, doloremque, aspernatur.</p>
</div>
```

In my approach, I used a CSS class for body to toggle the `overflow` state. When `body` gets the class (`.modalview`) it will hide content below the fold and remove scrollbars from page while showing the actual modal.

jQuery is used to apply the class to body and show `#modal` through a `on` click function.

For demonstration sake, I made the `#modal` show up when you just click on the page, you can bind the function to a button click, like so:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("modalview");
})
```

To see this properly, load up the **[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/n4naea92/)** and play with the page width to see how the scrolling is changed.